# Random behaviour while deleting bucket from S3

Tags: asp.net, amazon-s3, c#-4.0, chilkat

I am working on the code that interacts with **Aws s3** to perform various operations like create bucket, Delete bucket, upload and download files and so on.
An issue is occurring while trying to delete the bucket; *Access Denied*

At present, I am using *Root user* credentials to create and delete the bucket. No versioning is enabled and could not see any bucket Policy in AWS Console attached to this bucket.

It is showing strange behaviour; sometimes gives access denied error while trying to delete the empty bucket , sometime it just gets delete effortlessly.

I am able to delete the bucket via AWs s3 console without any trouble. It is just through the code it is behaving random.

Can please somebody explain; what could be the reason?

here is my code

```
public string DeleteBucket(string bucketName, string S3Region)
{
    string sts = "";
   
    Chilkat.Http http = new Chilkat.Http();

    // Insert your access key here:
    http.AwsAccessKey = "AccessKey";
    http.AwsSecretKey = "SecretKey";  //root user
    http.AwsRegion = S3Region;
    

    bool success = http.S3_DeleteBucket(bucketName);
    
    if (success != true)
    {
        
        return sts = "{\"Status\":\"Failed\",\"Message\":\""http.lastErrorText"\"}";
    }
    else
    {
        return sts = "{\"Status\":\"Success\",\"Message\":\"Bucket deleted!\"}";
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer your question about why you get Access Denied, but there's much more support for the SDK provided by AWS https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-net/

Answer (score 1):

You should examine the HTTP response body to see the error message from AWS.
For example:

```
http.KeepResponseBody = true;

bool success = http.S3_DeleteBucket(bucketName);

if (success != true) {
    Debug.WriteLine(http.LastErrorText);
    // Also examine the error response body from AWS:
    Debug.WriteLine(http.LastResponseBody);
}
else {
    Debug.WriteLine("Bucket created.");
}
```